# What are eth_getWork parameters?

Tags: mining, mining-pools

I was looking over at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getwork and I don't understand some of the parameters:

- DATA, 32 Bytes - current block header pow-hash
- DATA, 32 Bytes - the seed hash used for the DAG.
- DATA, 32 Bytes - the boundary condition ("target"), 2^256 / difficulty.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the first parameter the hash of the whole block or just header?
   (is transaction tree included)
2. Where does the seed hash come from? Is it deterministic? Is every miner receiving the same seed hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the first parameter the hash of the whole block or just header? (is
>   transaction tree included)

The first parameter is the hash of the block *header*, not the entire block. The header includes the *root* of the transaction trie, but the trie itself is stored in the main part of the block, outside of the header.

More formally, the first parameter is the hash of the *truncated* block header, which includes neither the *nonce* or *mix-hash* components that a complete block header normally has.

> Where does the seed hash come from? Is it deterministic? Is every
>   miner receiving the same seed hash?

- It's based on the [current block number](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash#defining-the-seed-hash) and which epoch we're in. (An epoch is 30,000 blocks.) This is the same for everyone mining the same block, and so...
- ...yes, it's deterministic, so...
- ...yes.

Note that even though seed generation is deterministic for a given block, the DAG is generated from this seed using a [pseudorandomly generated cache](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash#cache-generation) (using the [MemoHash](http://www.hashcash.org/papers/memohash.pdf) algorithm). Which means the DAG will (almost certainly) be different for every miner.

**Sources:**

- The [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf)

  - *(48)*, *(49)*, page 6
  - *Dataset generation*, page 31
- [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) wiki entry

Comment: mkcache seems very deterministic for me, where is the pseudorandom part?

Comment: It's not too obvious from the algorithm, but it uses unpredictable memory accesses as its source of randomness (or at least pseudorandomness). Section 5 of the MemoHash paper explains this in more detail: http://www.hashcash.org/papers/memohash.pdf